# Oracle Spool to CSV Formatting Issue

Tags: oracle, csv, oracle11gr2, spool

I wish to export a two column table to CSV using the Oracle Spool. When I execute the export, the first column formats fine, the second column however spills over into a third column in XLS. The contents of the second column in the DB are quite long.

Below is what I am trying:

```
column MachineName Format a20;
column OperatorName Format a32000;
set colsep ,
set echo off
set feedback off
set heading on
set linesize 32000
set pagesize 0
set termout off
set trim off
set trimspool on
set array 100
set underline off
set wrap off
set flush off
set verify off
set embedded on
```

Below are the results. In this example, the "Lucio Victor" should be in the same column as "Revolo Borja". (In the DB, this is all in one column)

```
MACHINENAME         ,OPERATORNAME
CM101               ,Revolo Borja, Lucio Victor
CM101               ,Revolo Borja, Lucio Victor
CM101               ,Revolo Borja, Lucio Victor
CM101               ,Revolo Borja, Lucio Victor
```

Results should be

```
MACHINENAME         ,OPERATORNAME
CM101               ,Revolo Borja Lucio Victor
CM101               ,Revolo Borja Lucio Victor
CM101               ,Revolo Borja Lucio Victor
CM101               ,Revolo Borja Lucio Victor
```

Comment: for what it's worth, in SQLcl (still in beta), you can have your output automatically formatted to CSV. SQLcl is a new command line interface developed by the SQL Developer team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put " around your operatorname column, excel is reading the comma as a field delimeter

Comment: I think I have just figured out why....but don't know how to fix. When I look at the raw data for that column it is like this: